# SQL Server: Insert an aggregate value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have spent some time researching this but have not found an answer.

So I have one table called `WinterInspectionResults`, and I have another Table called `InspectionResulsts`, and what I want to do is insert values from the first table into the second table.
The thing is some cases `WinterInspectionResults` will have multiple entries that correspond to one entry in `InspectionResults`.  So I use the `sum()` function.
The problem is when I try to insert I get the error:

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_InspectionResults'. 
Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.InspectionResults'.
```

So, maybe I don't understand exactly how aggregate functions work.
Has anyone else experienced this and/or know how to get around it?
Also `dbo.InspectionResults` has a aggregate key, that is the combination of two foreign keys.

Thanks for the help I figured out what the problem was.

Comment: Some table strucutres and SQL would be helpful. I'm guessing you'll need to write some T-SQL with a temp table, but I don't know what it'd look like exactly without a bit more information.

Comment: please show us some code

Comment: can you post your table structure and your query that you are using that is generating the error?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that its not a problem with your `SUM`, but that you are trying to insert values that already exists on `InspectionResults`. You should verify that you are not inserting duplicates. Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO InspectionResults(List of your columns)
SELECT A.*
FROM (  SELECT [Key Columns Of InspectionResults], SUM([Agreggated Column])
        FROM WinterInspectionResults
        GROUP BY [Key Columns Of InspectionResults]) A
LEFT JOIN InspectionResults B
ON A.[Key Columns Of InspectionResults] = B.[Key Columns Of InspectionResults]
WHERE B.[Key Columns Of InspectionResults] IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming your tables are made of ID and value only. Any other fields you can adjust.
What you are missing is the check to not insert the values that are already on InspectionResulsts

```
insert into InspectionResulsts (ID, VALUE)
select WI.ID, SUM(WI.VALUE)
from WinterInspectionResults WI
where WI.ID not in (select ID from InspectionResulsts)
```